# Encoding issue in Eclipse incorrectly displays UTF-8 characters that have no issue in other editors

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

I have a previously archived Eclipse project that I need to rebuild and publish because of a program error. Unfortunately, all of the french characters in my Java files (not ideal, I know) are shown as question marks. This was not an issue when I was using Eclipse 2.x, but I recently upgraded to Eclipse 3.x. All of the file encodings appear to be correct, and there is no problem with xml files, just .java source files. I'm using MacOS and the 64-bit version of eclipse. An image describing the problem is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAZF7.png).

Thanks!

Comment: You can change the file encoding somewhere in file-> properties

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a font for the text editor that supports the used UTF-8 characters. Go to `Window/Preferences/General/Appearance/Colors and Fonts` and change the "Text" fonts in the category "Basic" to a font, that supports the french UTF-8 characters. To read the files in the Java editor you will have to do the same for the corresponding fonts under the category "Java".